# Dojo Singleton or at least static method/variable?

Tags: javascript, dojo

does anyone know how to make a Dojo Class a singleton, or at least how to create a static method or variable in a dojo class?

I currently achieve this by having a global Variable for each class and a method that sets this variable if its null, but this is a crappy solution. Having a singleton class would be much nicer because one could inherit from it and voilá has a singleton :)

heinrich

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `dojo.declareClass` to create a new class, you can always use `new` operator to create a new instance of it. In Java, the singleton is implemented using private constructor, but JavaScript doesn't have this kind of capability. So you can not create the Java-like singleton in JavaScript.

So my typical way to create a singleton is :

```
if (typeof dojo.getObject('x.y.z') === 'undefined') {
    dojo.setObject('x.y.z', {
       //object definitions
    });
}
```

To create a static variable, just add the variable to the dojo class object.

```
dojo.declare("x.y.ABC", {});
x.y.ABC.globalV = 'abc';
```

When used with `dojo.require`, a JavaScript file won't be loaded twice by dojo, so you don't need to check the existence of a variable.

Answer (score 15):

The pattern for a singleton object in JavaScript is defined pretty well by the following article as background information:
http://kaijaeger.com/articles/the-singleton-design-pattern-in-javascript.html

To Dojo-tize this, using 1.7+ we need to capture the original constructor function in a closure so that nobody outside of the closure has access to the original and provide an
accessor method that always returns the same instance, no matter who tries to get a
reference to it...

It also makes sense to have the method that turns a "class" constructor Function into a singleon as a shareable, reuseable, piece of code. My preference in Dojo, is to have this
as its own "module" as a utility method (not a Dojo class object), so here we go...

**MakeSingleton.js**

```
define(['dojo/_base/lang'], function(lang)
{
  return function(ctor) {   // not defining a class, just a utility method.
      var singletonCtor,    // our singleton constructor function.
          instance = null;  // singleton instance provided to any clients.

      // define the singleton constructor with accessor method.
      // (captures 'ctor' parameter and 'instance' variable in a function
      //  closure so that they are available whenever the getInstance() method
      //  on the singleton is called.)
      singletonCtor = new function() {       // note: 'new' is important here!!
          this.getInstance = function() {    // our accessor function
              if (!instance) {               // captures instance in a closure
                instance = new ctor();       // create instance using original ctor.
                instance.constructor = null; // remove instance's constructor method
              }                              //  so you cannot use new operator on it!!
              return instance;               // this is our singleton instance.
          }  
      };  

      // Since we are working with Dojo, when declaring a class object, if you
      // provide a 'className' as the first parameter to declare(...), Dojo will
      // save that value in the 'declaredClass' property on the object's prototype...
      // ... and adds a reference to that constructor function in the global namespace
      // as defined by the 'className' string.
      //
      // So if 'declaredClass' has a value, we need to close the hole by making
      // sure this also refers to the singleton and not the original constructor !!
      //
      if (ctor.prototype && ctor.prototype.declaredClass) {
        lang.setObject(ctor.prototype.declaredClass, singletonCtor);
      }

      // return the singleton "constructor" supports only a getInstance() 
      // method and blocks the use of the 'new' operator.
      return singletonCtor;

  }; // return "MakeSingleton" method
};  // define(...)
```

So how do we use this in Dojo 1.7+ when we want to define a Singleton class object?
Pretty easy since we have already done the heavy lifting above...

**MySingletonClass.js**

```
define(['dojo/_base_declare', 'MakeSingleton'], 
       function(declare, MakeSingleton)
{
    return MakeSingleton( declare('MySingletonClass', [...], {
                          // Define your class here as needed...
                        }));  
});
```

So what is going on here...
The result of calling declare(...) is passed directly into the MakeSingleton(...) utility
method, so the original class constructor (Function) created by Dojo is never made public, and if a 'className' was passed into declare(...), MakeSingleton has also made sure that
is not the original constructor, but the singleton object.  Furthermore, the export from 
this module is also the singleton object (MakeSingleton's return value), so the Dojo
loader only has a reference to the singleton after running the factory method.  The
original constructor class is captured within a closure of the singleton object, so
nobody else can get to it and create an additional instance...
**we truly have a singleton**.

So how do we get access to this singleton... If you do not specify a 'className' when you
declare your class, the only way to get at it is through a module dependency reference. If you did specify a 'className' as in the example above (shame, shame), you can access it
from the global name space (which is **NOT** the way Dojo is headed, use the module dependency reference).

The result of calling the exported method of the MakeSingleton.js utility module is an
object that has a single method on it called getInstance().  getInstance() will create
an instance of the original class object on its first call, and return that same instance on every successive call.  If you try to use 'new' on the singleton class, it will generate an error. If you try to use 'new' on the reference in the global namespace (if
you provided a 'className' to declare), it will generate an error.  The **only** way to
get a hold of the instance is to call the singleton's getInstance() method.

**SomeOtherModule.js**

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare', 'MySingletonClass'],
       function(declare, MySingletonClass) 
{
    return declare(null, { 
        mySingleton: null,    // here we will hold our singleton reference.
        constructor: function(args) {
            ...
            // capture the singleton...
            mySingleton = MySingletonClass.getInstance();
            ... 
            mySingleton.doSomething(...);
        };

        mySpecialSauce: function(...) {
            mySingleton.doSomethingElse(...);
        };

        moreSauce: function(...) {
            var x;
            x = MySingletonClass.getInstance(); // gets same instance.
            x = new window.MySingletonClass();  // generates an error!!
            x = new MySingletonClass();         // generates an error!!
            // Dojo's loader reference generates an error as well !!
            x = new require.modules['MySingletonClass'].result(); 
        };
    });
});
```

It does not matter how many modules, classes, script elements, etc. get a reference to the
singleton object, they will all be referring to the same instance and 'new' ones cannot be
created.

Comment: This worked quite nicely.  A few minor typos above to be aware of.  (1) In the define of MySingleton you need to return singletonCtor.  (2) the getInstance() in MySingleton should be getInstance = and finally (3) the declareClass stuff should be using ctor and not a_ctor.  Nicely written up though!

Comment: @JonS The link at the beginning of your post doesn't lead to anything useful, please correct.

Answer (score 8):

```
require(["dojo/_base/declare"], function (declare) {
var o =
    declare("com.bonashen.Singleton", null, {
        say : function (name) {
            console.log("hello," + name);
        }
    });
//define static getInstance function for com.bonashen.Signleton class.
console.debug("define getInstance function. ");
o.getInstance = function () {
    if (null == o._instance)
        o._instance = new o();
    return o._instance;
};});
```

Answer (score 8):

Okay, no one actually gave a good answer to this for dojo 1.7+ AMD (that you can require in other files, et cetera)
Here's what I have:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
], function(
    declare
) {
    var SingletonClass = declare("SingletonClass", [], {
        field: 47, 
        method: function(arg1) {
            return field*5;
        }
    });
    if (!_instance) {
        var _instance = new SingletonClass();
    }
    return _instance;
});
```

It seems to work quite well, and make good sense.

Comment: You can just `return new SingletonClass()` since the value of a module is only determined once.

Comment: this actually works well, but (!_instance) will break in some browsers since it's undefined. on the other hand if(typeof(_instance) == 'undefined') works.

Answer (score 3):

Why not check for the creation of the singleton in the constructor function like:

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare'], function (declare) {

    var singletonClass = declare(null, {

        someProperty: undefined,

        constructor: function () {
           if (singletonClass.singleton)
              throw new Error('only one instance of singletonClass may be created');

           this.someProperty = 'initial value';
        }
     });

     // create the one and only instance as a class property / static member
     singletonClass.singleton = new singletonClass();

     return singletonClass;
});
```

Then use it like:

```
define(["app/singletonClass"], function(singletonClass) {
    var instance = singletonClass.singleton;  // ok
    var newInstance = new singletonClass();   // throws Error
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Why all this code to make a Dojo singleton? Is it not sufficient to return a new Class() in the module?

eg:

module:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare){
var TestApp = declare(null, {
    constructor: function(){
        console.log("constructor is called only once");
        this.key = Math.random();
        console.log("generated key: "+this.key);
    },
    sayHello : function(){
        console.log("sayHello: "+this.key);
    }
});
return new TestApp();
});
```

test:

```
    <script>
    require(['simplemodule.js'], function (amodule) {
        amodule.sayHello();
        console.log("first require");
    });

    require(['simplemodule.js'], function (amodule) {
        amodule.sayHello();
        console.log("second require");
    });


    require(['simplemodule.js'], function (amodule) {
        amodule.sayHello();
        console.log("third require");
    });

</script>
```

output:

```
constructor is called only once simplemodule.js:4
generated key: 0.6426086786668748 simplemodule.js:6
sayHello: 0.6426086786668748 simplemodule.js:9
first require test.html:15
sayHello: 0.6426086786668748 simplemodule.js:9
second require test.html:20
sayHello: 0.6426086786668748 simplemodule.js:9
third require
```

Answer (score 2):

Thinking about instances of classes in javascript does not always make sense. If you do not want to override any previous defined object, you can do the following:

```
something.myObject = something.myObject || {
    //Here you build the object
}
```

So, you would get the previous defined `something.myObject` if it is already defined, or (using `||`) you build the new object with `{}`. Any modifications to the object remain, as you only build a new object, if it is a falsy value before.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I make my singletons in Dojo:

```
var makeSingleton = function (aClass) {
    aClass.singleton = function () {
        var localScope = arguments.callee;
        localScope.instance = localScope.instance || new aClass();
        return localScope.instance;
    };
    return aClass;
};

makeSingleton(dojo.declare(...));
```

Then, to use it:

```
myClass.singleton()
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider declaring a single tone object in the following manner (Dojo 1.10), it uses a closure to keep reference of an instance in the module and add methods to the prototype of a function.

A good article on the topic can be found [here](http://unscriptable.com/2011/09/22/amd-module-patterns-singleton/).

```
define([

], function (

    ) {
    'use strict';
    var _instance;
    function _SingleTone() {
    }
    _SingleTone.prototype = {
        init: function () {
        }
    };
    return function _getSingleton() {
        return (_instance = (_instance || new _SingleTone()));
    };
});
```